# Melt ice faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, experimental-technique, ice

I had a discussion with a friend who claimed that vinegar is useful when defrosting a freezer because it lowers water's melting/freezing point. I disagreed, because I believe that the freezing point is irrelevant as long as the surrounding temperature is significantly higher that 0 ℃ (which it typically is in a normal household kitchen) - you still have to spend the same amount of energy to melt a certain amount of water, no matter the freezing point, so what matters is how fast you can transfer the necessary energy.

Who is right?

Notes:

1 I can accept that lowering the melting point slightly (e.g., to -5 ℃) might make the defrosting process marginally faster because I reckon that the ice would melt slightly faster if the difference between the melting point and the surrounding temperature (typically around 20 ℃) is 25 ℃ instead of 20 ℃. However, I expect that effect to be quite small.

2 Our argument occurred when I said that it is faster to use hot water to defrost (e.g., put in a sauce pan with boiling water on a shelf in the freezer) than vinegar, simply because hot water contains much more energy, and transfers that energy faster, than air at room temperatur.

Comment: Mind you, I'd say I'm not very keen on having my freezer smell like vinegar...

Comment: Consider: salt is often used to melt snow & ice on roads.

Comment: @Jon Well, it's a good mould killer. ;) I guess you can neutralise it afterwards with bicarb soda, which is also an odour neutraliser, and is often recommended for cleaning fridges & freezers.